# Node js Y mongodb no me traen los datos a un formulario

Tags: nodejs, mongodb

tengo un error que no me permite traer datos a un formlario el error que me da es

```
Handlebars: Access has been denied to resolve the property "_id" because it is not an "own property" of its parent.
You can add a runtime option to disable the check or this warning:
See https://handlebarsjs.com/api-reference/runtime-options.html#options-to-control-prototype-access for details.
```

**código**

```
router.get('/notes/edit/:id', async (req,res) => {
  const note  = await Note.findById(req.params.id)
  res.render('notes/edit-note', { note })
})
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61346190/13024973

Comment: pudiste solucionar el problema ?

Answer (score 0):

```
router.get('/notes/edit/:id', async (req, res) => {
    const editar = await Note.findById(req.params.id).lean();
    res.render('notes/edit-note', { editar });

});
```

Esta es la solución me lo soluciono el parametro .lean(); ya que mongodb deniega el acceso por medio de la variable cambie el nota por editar para que se mas intuitivo